# Zoom in/out keyboard shortcuts for Swedish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, aperture

I could not get the keyboard shortcuts for zoom in/out in Aperture 3 on my Swedish Keyboard.

According to the documentation it should be <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>

I have searched the Internet, but it only shows the same as above.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd check which keyboard shortcuts are documented for zoom in/out in the relevant menu.  My View menu (in Aperture 3.4.4) is as shown below: note the keyboard shortcuts to the right of the menu option.

[image: Aperture View menu]

I read that '=' is <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>0</kbd> on a Swedish keyboard.  On my UK keyboard, '=' has a key to itself (pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd> produces '-'), so I'd guess that the issue is to do with the <kbd>shift</kbd> key.

So, secondly, a different approach -- if we can't work out how to generate this key combination on a Swedish keyboard, I'd suggest changing the keyboard shortcut.  To do this, go to Apple menu > System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts.  Select Application Shortcuts on the left.  Press the '+' button, then select *Aperture* as the application, type *Zoom In* for Menu Title (making sure you get the spellling and capitalisation exactly right), and then type the key combination you'd like to use in the Keyboard Shortcut box.

[image]

Finally, if you are eligible for software support, I'd suggest calling AppleCare and asking them for help...

Comment: Mine does show the same, but the keyboard shortcuts as shown does not work. My guess is because I have a Swedish keyboard where the '=' & '-' are not on the same place as on English keyboards.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson OK... confusing stuff! I've edited my answer to include a few more suggestions... see what you think.